# Is it possible for two instances of the SHA256 encryption to be equal?

Tags: encryption

We are using SHA256 encryption in an email, the idea is that the Subscriber key will be the email address, and when it comes to click through urls we’d include the hashed value of the email (using SHA256) so that we can then match the activity back to the specific user in the CDP (CDP will also be using SHA256 so that it can act as a join key for any click through url specific activity). Any other data or activity can then be tied back to the CDP simply using the email address.

This is the script:

```
%%[ SET @CheckForEmail = IsEmailAddress(_SubscriberKey) 
    IF @CheckForEmail == 'false' THEN 
      SET @FinalSubscriberKey = _SubscriberKey 
    ELSE 
      SET @FinalSubscriberKey = SHA256(_SubscriberKey,'UTF-16') 
    ENDIF 
    SET @Link = CONCAT('https://landingpageurlhere?hashed_email=', @FinalSubscriberKey) 
]%%
```

Here is the CTA link: `%%=RedirectTo(@Link)=%%`

My client used an online SHA256 checker and said it didn't match the landing page encryption.

So, is there a way to "match" two encryptions?

Answer (score 2):

Note that hashing is not *encryption*, but rather an *irreversible cryptographic function*. Two identical strings, passed through a hashing function such as SHA256, will result in identical output.

Your code appears to have a bug. The AMPScript function IsEmailAddress returns a Boolean value, which is either `true` or `false`, without the quotes. While I'm not well-versed in AMPScript, it seems your code should read more like this:

```
%%[ SET @CheckForEmail = IsEmailAddress(_SubscriberKey) 
    IF @CheckForEmail == false THEN 
      SET @FinalSubscriberKey = _SubscriberKey 
    ELSE 
      SET @FinalSubscriberKey = SHA256(_SubscriberKey,'UTF-16') 
    ENDIF 
    SET @Link = CONCAT('https://landingpageurlhere?hashed_email=', @FinalSubscriberKey) 
]%%
```

The reason why your SHA256 didn't match is because you ran SHA256 on your SHA256 subscriber key, resulting in yet another hash.